# Can you access an iPhone's phone number via code in an app?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Can you access an iPhone's phone number via code in an app?
This seems like a security problem but I was wondering whether anyone could definitively answer it.

Comment: Yep, its a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)