# Path for info plist in case of device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can any one tell in case of device path of info plist,& where our own phone number is stored ?

Answer (score 0):

You can ref to this post for the answer.

[Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Comment: This will give us a number that is already saved in my own number,& in that we can save number which ever we want,i dont want that ,i want my phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the `Info.plist`. You probably don't want to be accessing anything of that sort at runtime. It is indeed possible to retrieve the phone number from `NSUserDefaults`, but I recommend that you just ask the user to select his own contact, or even just enter in his own phone number. That's a little bit less surprising and scary, security-wise.

Comment: Because I want My own mobile number & by NSUserDefaults we get no that is saved by us in my own number ,it can be any number that we saved,i dont want that,i want my mobile number.