# How to get my phone number from iphone

Tags: ios4

I want to get my phone number. with the coding in iphone is their any way or code to get my phone number.

I am using following code for the finding of my phone number but i am getting 1(1234)12345
In simulator it is giving null value.

```
NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];
```

Is their any other framework to include in my application.

Comment: I think the method you are using is returning the phone number that was entered at the time of activation with iTunes. I dont know if you can get the "Sim Card" phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) - the following code snippet should help?

```
NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                 stringForKey:@”SBFormattedPhoneNumber”];

NSLog(@”Phone Number: %@”, num);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the developer license forbids access to the SIM number.  The best you can do is get the number entered to activate iTunes.