# How to auto populate phone number from iphone?

Tags: ios4, ios-4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

I am developing an iOS 4.1 application that need to get the phone number of the user. I have tried the blow code to get the phone number. But it is not working.

NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];

is there any way to get the phone number in iOS 4.1 ?

Thanks,
Shinto

Answer (score 0):

In short there is no approved way to do this.

This is a duplicate question see [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) for more info.