# How can I get the phone number of my iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

I am new in iPhone technology. I am currently building a dialler application in which requires the phone number of my iPhone form my SIM card.

How can I get the phone number of my iPhone device?

Comment: Also, user758741, there's a good chance your dialer may be rejected from the app store.  They rejected Google Voice, and I've heard rumors of other dialers being rejected.  However, there is a Skype app, and they support voip-based apps.

Comment: This question is answered in depth on another thread.  Check it out at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os

Answer (score 5):

The phone number is not accessable from any Apple public API which means you can't get it.

If you are implementing a dialer application I can't see what you would nee the own phone number for. It's not like you are going to call yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the users phone number from the NSUserDefault:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]
```

But this will only work if the user has entered his phone number.
There is no way in the official SDK to read anything from the SIM card.