# Is there a private API available to access the SIM Toolkit?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I'm investigating what APIs are available for accessing the SIM toolkit, does anything exist?

(Yes I know any use of such an API wouldn't permit the app to be submitted to the app store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can take a look at CoreTelephony framework (disassemble it). It has bunch of functions around SimToolkit like:

- CTServerConnectionCopySimToolkitMenu
- CTServerConnectionSelectSimToolkitMenuItem
  and so on.

2)You can take a look (disassemble) at /System/Library/SpringBoardPlugins/SimToolkitUI.servicebundle/SimToolkitUI

You will be able to see what functions are used there (you will see a lot of functions from #1)