# Is it possible to get iphone's phone number programmatically in 2011?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-number, sim-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Is it still impossible to get user's phonenumber in iOS and have your app accepted to appStore like they say in this thread: [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) ?
I hope that something's changed since then.

What are the good alternatives?

Comment: FYI: Going the `NSUserDefault` route got us rejected from the app store about 2 years ago, and we were only using it to prefill a form.

Answer (score 3):

No is not possible to get phone number by code.

but you can always ask the user their phone number using a model window..

Answer (score 2):

Still not possible. For good reasons.