# How to obtain the iPhone telephone number

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to use the iPhone mobile phone numbers as part of the security in my app. How would I go about doing this or if not possible, how could I obtain the UID number.

It believe it is possible to do this with Android or Winmobile phones.

Comment: What about iPods and iPads? Are you going to make your application not work on those devices, and thus suffer sales losses?

Comment: Try the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres Apples recomendation for using the UID

> A device’s unique identifier
> (sometimes abbreviated as UDID for
> Unique Device Identifier) is a hash
> value composed from various hardware
> identifiers such as the device serial
> number. It is guaranteed to be unique
> for each device. The UDID is
> independent of the device name. For
> devices that use a SIM (subscriber
> identity module) card, the UDID is
> independent of the SIM card.
>
> For user security and privacy, you
> must not publicly associate a device’s
> unique identifier with a user account.
>
> You may use the UDID, in conjunction
> with an application-specific user ID,
> for identifying application-specific
> data on your server. For example, you
> use could a device-user combination ID
> to control access to registered
> products or when storing high scores
> for a game in a central server.
> However, if you are developing a game,
> you may want to instead use Game
> Center’s player identifier key as
> explained in Game Kit Programming
> Guide.
>
> Important: Never store user
> information based solely on the UDID.
> Always use a combination of UDID and
> application-specific user ID. A
> combined ID ensures that if a user
> passes a device on to another user,
> the new user will not have access to
> the original user’s dat

So it looks like if you are using this for storing data on a server you can use the UDID and a ID that you generate. Also it looks like Apple has gotten rid of many of the older ways that you would use to access the phone number.

Answer (score 3):

There is [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) which has the `uniqueIdentifier` property

Comment: That can be faked very easily. I do not suggest using that for security, although I honestly don't know what else you could use (besides the device's serial number, which can be gotten, but apple doesn't like it)

Comment: Thats not the phone number and this is a re post of a question. Loook here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os'

Comment: I never said it was the phone number - the question asked if the number could not be obtained, could the UID number be gotten.

Comment: phone number *or* UID. He only wants the UDID if grabbing the number is not possible.

Comment: And since using that method is likely to get you rejected from the App Store…