# Can I get a user's phone number using any of the Titanium API's?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

When a user runs my app (iOS or Android), can I automatically get their phone number and contact details for back up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't vouch for Android but for iOS the answer is a definite **no**. Here's what Apple will say when they reject your app:

> For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including
>   its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system.
>   This restriction is part of the security feature known as the
>   application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls
>   limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network
>   resources, hardware, and so on."
>
> The device's phone number is not available within your application's
>   container. You will need to revise your application to read only
>   within your directory container and resubmit your binary to iTunes
>   Connect in order for your application to be reconsidered for the App
>   Store.

See [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os) for additional notes.