# How to get iPhone phone number from a webapp?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-number

Is it possible to get the phone number or a unique ID identifying the phone from a WebApp on the iphone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Comment: Do you honestly want websites getting your cell phone number when you visit them?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is a popup warning me of this I don't mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, too large of a privacy/security issue.