# Can we get phone number in j2me programmatically?

Tags: mobile, java-me

Can we get phone number of device in j2me? Is it possible or not?

Comment: this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289494/how-to-get-phone-number-in-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AKAIK You can't. Its not possible. Because phone number mostly stored in SIM card, not in phone.

Also look at this [nice explanation](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?95101-Phone-Number&p=259193&viewfull=1#post259193).

Comment: hi bharath,Thanks for ur answer,actually i am using charging gateway in my application with midp 1.0 which requires phone number,so is there any other way to implement this.

Comment: @ bindal, Better you can ask user to enter the phone number manually.