# How to get the emulator's phone number in midlet?

Tags: java-me, midp, phone-number

Usually the emulator's phone number is displayed on itself (example: 0555555555).

I want to get that number from midlet.

In other words, is there any method to retrieve the emulator's or phone's mobile number ?

Comment: can't be done - see the answer to older question **[How to get phone number in J2ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289494/how-to-get-phone-number-in-j2me)**

Comment: Thank You gnat. I searched in StackOvf.. But I couldn't find that. I read it and solved my question.