# Getting Unique Id from all java phones especially from S40 devices

Tags: java-me, nokia-s40, imei, unique-id, jsr82

I have requirement of getting an unique identification number programmatically from all j2me supported phones.

As we already know getting IMEI / IMSI in S40 devices is almost not possible, bluetooth MAC address / obex push profile UUID may help. But for this, bluetooth should be turned on in mobile. And I don't know how many devices will support jsr82.

Is there some other unique id which will differentiate j2me devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just now i got answer from other source:
 There are no other unique IDs than IMEI, Bluetooth or WLAN (when available) MAC addresses. Redesign your solution not to depend on such entirely, or so that some ID you generate/assign yourself is sufficient (possibly in conjuntion with a username/password combination).

Any other ideas?

Comment: You can get the phone number of the user, but this will need to be from the operator side. They can embed the user's number in a url call. Alternatively if the app is operator signed then you may be able to talk to the SIM card to get the phone number, but i am not 100% certain of this.

Comment: @Ajibola [sim card does not store your phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7291790/839601 "as explained here")

Comment: Seems it stores International Mobile Subscriber Identity (IMSI), more info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289494/how-to-get-phone-number-in-j2me?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Use the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` when the user first starts the app.  Unless two users start their app at precisely the same millisecond (v. unlikely), this will be unique.