# How to check data connectivity ,phn number, operator name in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I used `System.getProperty("wireless.messaging.sms.smsc")` but it is showing some other number. How to get mobile number, operator of the SIM which is used and to check data connectivity.

Comment: what j2me version ? CLDC? MIDP? As far as I can remember how to obtain the information you seek was (if at all possible) device and vendor dependent. So vendor and model might help, too.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I am working with MIDP model  is Nokia and vendor is AIRTEL

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. What would be helpful would be your **J2ME** **Version**. J2ME is split up into **CLDC** (Connected Limited Device Configuration) and **MIDP** (Mobile Information Device Profile). Both the CLDC version and the MIDP version would be of interest. Further more, the specific device you are using and what additional libraries are supported by that device is important, too. you can find a list of libraries associated with J2ME [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition)

Comment: Thank you for providing document ,but I need system property to display phone number which I am using. I am beginner so only I don't know how to search for vendor also...

Comment: I want exact code to read phn number , anybody know about that ???

Answer (score 0):

Ok, short answer: You can't get the phone number.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289494/how-to-get-phone-number-in-j2me)

The properties you have to read to get thinks like *IMSI, MNC, MCC* are completely vendor/model specific so unless you can't give these refer to [this post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1700493)

Concerning connectivity, I am not sure whether you mean availability of internet or wireless connectivity or something else. But in most cases the answer would be: You will have to check if the device vendor offers an SDK for that.

Comment: Is there no way to get phone number . Or like IMSI,MNC AND MCC as input is there is any way to display????

Comment: Ok then how to check whether device vendor offers SDK??