# Is it possible to get the current user's address book record?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

Assuming the user has granted permission for the app to access contacts, is there any way to determine which record belongs to the phone owner? For example if you browse the list of contacts on your phone, you will see a little "me" beside the record that is identified as the owner's record. So the phone clearly knows this, but is there any programmatic way to determine this? Or is that considered a privacy violation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know on a Mac you can use `[[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me]`. For iOS, take a look at how [Square's CardCase app does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000927).

Comment: Looks like this might not be available on iOS unfortunately.

Comment: That's correct. There is no `[AB me]` equivalent in the iOS API. However

Comment: What about `CNContactStore`? Is it possible to get it?