# kABPerson Property | to know if an AddressBook contact is using also iPhone?

Tags: ios, properties, addressbook

I'm trying to develop an app, where users can send messages via `iMessage`. So I'm able to import the contact list from `AddressBook`, and to send Messages via `MessageUI Framework`, but I will like to know which of the contacts imported have also iPhone so they can use `iMessage` capability. Is there any way to find out from the `kABPerson`...Property?

Here my code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

 CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

             NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
             NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));

             //Something like this ?
             BOOL *doeshaveiPhone = (__bridge BOOL *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel));


             NSLog(@"Name:%@ Surname: %@", firstName, lastName);


            ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

            for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
            {
                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
                CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
                NSString *phoneLabel =(__bridge NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
                CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
                CFRelease(locLabel);
                NSLog(@" - %@ (%@)", phoneNumber, phoneLabel);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the best way to determine if people in the Address Book have iMessage. However, there is a disadvantage: **it only works if the user properly sets up their contacts.** Too often, fields are improperly set which can make developing applications difficult.

This question has been asked before. [Here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509253/2035473) the top-voted answer says,

> your heurisitic might be ok but it relies on the USER correctly
>   setting that attribute.
>
> depending on the context it might be good enough / or not .. dont
>   know.
>
> there is no real way to detect which user really uses ios (no API)