# How to get a phone's number in React Native?

Tags: react-native

With React Native, how do you get the number of the current phone?

Along the same lines, can I get the user's name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot. This cannot be done using iOS public APIs and therefore cannot be done via React Native.

Comment: Really? Wow... ok. What about their first name, at least?

Comment: The best you can do is "guess" at it by looking at the most likely match in their contacts. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000927/how-does-squares-cardcase-app-automatically-populate-the-users-details-from-th/8058188#8058188

Comment: An other way is use a two factor authentication like whatsapp : https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-implement-sms-verification-like-WhatsApp-in-my-iPhone-application

Comment: @efx What you linked to is nothing more than asking the user to input their phone number. Which is fine, and really is the industry standard for recording the phone number. But this doesn't address the original question - how to get the user's phone number _programmatically_.

Comment: What about Android?

Answer (score 3):

This npm plugin is great to detect phone numbers in a device. **react-native-sms-retriever**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever

import SmsRetriever from 'react-native-sms-retriever';

```
_onPhoneNumberPressed = async () => {
try {
  const phoneNumber = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();
  this.setState({phone: phoneNumber.split('+91')[1]});
} catch (error) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}}
```

Comment: no, this is a react native plugin based on android native.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's phone number (and much more), using [react-native-device-info library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getphonenumber).

But first make sure to [ask to user for permissions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-sms-retriever](https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever) which is using [HintRequest](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/verification-sms-automatically-with-sms-retriever-api-in-android/) only available for android

```
yarn add react-native-sms-retriever
```

```
import SmsRetriever from 'react-native-sms-retriever';
import {parsePhoneNumber} from 'awesome-phonenumber';

const openPhoneHintModal=async ()=>{
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        try {
          const phoneNumber = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();
          console.log(phoneNumber, 'phoneNumber');
          const pn = parsePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
          const countryCode = pn.getCountryCode();                       //92
          const regionCode = pn.getRegionCode();                         //PK
          const phoneWithoutCountryCode = pn.getNumber('significant');   //342955555X
        
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
     
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use library

**react-native-sim-cards-manager** v1.0.10

https://github.com/odemolliens/react-native-sim-cards-manager

Comprises of

https://github.com/markneh/react-native-esim

https://github.com/pocesar/react-native-sim-data

for Android API version > 29, change your permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
```

.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the [`react-native-sim` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sim) can do this on Android, though as @xanadont mentions, it's not currently possible on iOS.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sim. Github link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it @ArjunNayak.