# MonoTouch Way to get Own phone number and Sim Id(SSID)?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, phone-number, ssid

Im stuck to get own phone number and Sim ID (SSID) using Monotouch
I tryed:

```
var v = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ValueForKey((NSString)@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber");       
var t = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ValueForKey((NSString)@"ICCID");

new UIAlertView("Ur phone Number",""+v.ToString(),null,"Ok",null).Show();
new UIAlertView("Ur ICCID",""+t.ToString(),null,"Ok",null).Show();
```

and all other ValueFor***

it always return `null` or `" "`

Tried on iphone 3g. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does **[not](http://img.ly/dbZ)** want to to access this information as it can easily be misused. Any application doing so is likely to be **rejected** from the AppStore. See the comment (with more than 30 up votes) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224356/220643).

Also note that your code above does not read from the SIM - it reads from the iTunes registration data, which does not have to be set to any value (i.e. you **can't** trust it).