# is there an API call that gives you an iPhone user's "My Info" contact DB record?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

So in the latest iOS (not sure about prior) there is a "My Info" setting that let's the user pick a ContactDB record on his device that is "his".

Is there an API call to get this value?  I can query the user's entire ContactDB, but figuring out which contact DB is his isn't trivial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my own cell phone number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422237/how-can-i-get-my-own-cell-phone-number)

Answer (score 3):

There’s no public API that I know of to retrieve the user’s “me” card. Your best option is probably to present an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController asking the user to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I believe Bump had a setup step that asked for your contact info, and the moment you gave it your phone number (or email?) it looked up the contact card with the matching info and autofilled the rest of the form. A bit of a workaround, but it did the trick.