# iOS - detect the phone number / email address of the current device?

Tags: ios, email, detection, phone-number

If I have users using an app and I need to know their phone number of their iPhone, or their email that they use for iMessages (if it's an iTouch or something) can I detect that in anyway?

Comment: You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os, which requires SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not feasible with current sdk. if any how you can do this with private API, Apple will reject your app. May you can use this with jailbroken device.

Comment: Good, this is sad for a feature I wanted to include with my app but this is good that Apple protects user's data this well :)