# Getting iPhone Carrier Mobile Number in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get own phone number in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os)

Is there any possibility to Get the mobile number of iPhone user in an iPhone app through program...

Comment: not possible stop think about it :)

Comment: You would not be able to extract the phone number using any public APIs of iOS 6. Though following code use to work in iOS 3.0 > NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]

Comment: That is for Jailbroken devices. not works with appstore app