# Capture mobile number of application User

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

Is there a way such that the smart phone application will be able to fetch mobile number that is currently active in it. Is it something feasible?

Comment: On iOS this information is available.

Comment: check this link for iPhone

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-iphone-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) to do this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

You'll need to give your application [permission to make this query](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) by adding the following to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

(You shouldn't use `TelephonyManager.getDefault()` to get the `TelephonyManager` as [that is a private undocumented API call and may change in future](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c2a231ec44a9451c).)