# How to let one user send a request to another user only if they both have the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to have one user send a request to play the app with another user but only if the other user also has the app.  I have seen this done in snapchat it lets you add (or friend) people who also have snapchat.  I figure the user has to grant permission for the app to access contacts but after that I am pretty lost.  Does anyone have any links that discuss this?

Thanks

Comment: Require a login and email to use the app, and store that information on a server. When accessing the user's contacts, search for emails that match existing users and flag them as existing users.

Comment: That's a lot simpler then I thought it was going to be.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many apps ask for an email to log in or they ask for a mobile number and then find friends using the contact book with that data.

You request access to their contacts and upload them to your server. Make sure you are clear about what is happening. Path did this without clear disclosure and [people got worried.](http://www.theverge.com/2012/2/8/2785217/path-ios-address-book-upload-ceo-apology)

There is [no way to programmatically grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios) an iPhone's phone number so you have to ask for it.

TLDR:

1. Ask for email or mobile number
2. Ask for permission to contacts
3. Match those on your server and return results.

You could also theoretically use Facebook, but I don't have any experience with that API.