# Getting my contact info from address book

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've read tons of questions on how to get someone's else contact info from address book, but never found any topic related on how to get my own personal info (phone user info)? Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Not possible for security reasons. see [get phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. About phone number I understand, but the app I need to make is already done for android and android in default contacts app has this thing called "me profile" where you set up your first name, last name, emails, address etc.. basically it saves it like any other contact in you address book list. It is just flagged differently than other contacts. Not being familiar with iOS and only being starter, I assume 'me profile' doesn't exists on iOS?

Comment: Yes, there isn't, make user fill in a me profile in the app.