# compare the message body with string

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting confusion in sending the message to the current mobile and then i want to compare the text message body with string,is it possible to fetch the message details in iOS,

please let me know

**EDIT**
  or 
    can any one please help me how i wii verify my mobile number

thank you

Comment: i think you can't access messages in iOS.

Comment: are you composing a message using MFMessageComposeViewController ?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann  is there any way to verify my mobile number like whats up

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes i am using the MFMessageComposeViewController

Comment: Your question very very vague. When you say message are you talking about an email??

Comment: @popey my problem is i am sending the message to same phone for verification something,so how to verify that message through the message body or mobile number or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a delegate on MFMessageComposeViewController, you can detect when the user clicks "send" on it by overriding [`messageComposeViewController: didFinishWithResult:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate/messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:)

And the parameter that's sent in that function includes the view controller, so you can examine various pieces of it, including the message [`body`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MFMessageComposeViewController/body) and the [`recipients`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MFMessageComposeViewController/recipients).

As for verifying your mobile number, you need to rely on the user being honest and typing it in correctly. [You can not do it programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios).