# How did Swarm app get my phone number?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, cncontact

I gave Swarm access to my contacts to know who else were on Swarm.
To match me with the people in my address book, I was expecting Swarm to ask me for my phone number and start and SMS validation process.

It didn't.

And it could match me with my contacts.

What code did they use to get my phone number ?

Comment: It did ask you for access to your contacts?

Comment: @Undo Did you read the first sentence of the question?

Comment: Yes. But how do they get my own phone number ? Do you know the code ?

Comment: Old, but alot of useful information: [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/193182/2108547)

Comment: @DanielStorm the solution uses the private API and is thus rejected by the AppStore as pointed out by the most voted answer.

Comment: @Cherif I'm aware. I was trying to help you avoid wasting your time implementing something similar to what was already mentioned there.