# Is it posible to retrieve my own contact details from phone book?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I am using the `CNContact` framework to get all of the contacts from my phone and I need to compare some data with my own contact details.

Is it posible to get my own contact details ? I can find myself listed when retrieving the contacts using apple framework, but I don't know how to identify me .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you need more than just the phone number?

Comment: only phone number will be ok, if anything else is not possible

Comment: Looks like not, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685369/1316346

Comment: Is this app going to the store?  Or are you using it for personal use/jailbroken devices?  There are private APIs which exist for getting this information, but you can't release an app if you use them.

Comment: It's going to the store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to ask the SDK for the contact of the phone's owner.  If you have some information about the owner (like name), then your best bet is to query for contacts with a `CNContactFetchRequest` using what information you have.