# Can i get my info contact from all CNContact iOS?

Tags: ios, cncontact

I am working on a contact app. Currently, I use `CNContact` framework to access all contacts. How may I identify if a particular contact has set in my info?

Comment: I think this might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685369/2174668

Comment: Check this link too.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711273/is-it-posible-to-retrieve-my-own-contact-details-from-phone-book

Comment: I have get all contact with my info contact. can i identify that this contact is set to my info contact?

Comment: The question is unclear - I have the same need, but I could hardly understand  what you wanted here. Maybe "How may I identify the owner user's contact card, the one tagged as "me" ?"