# iOS get user's personal information from the device

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I am working on swift iOS health project that contains user profile with his/her personal info, I need a way to get user's personal info from the iPhone, can I get the device's mobile number and email from the medical ID or from "My Info" in contacts?

The question is not duplicated because I'm asking about iOS 9, the previous question is very old and there might be something new in the latest iOS, plus I asked if it is possible to get these info from the medical ID.

Comment: Have you Googled `iOS get user's personal information from the device`? There seems to be *some* info - if not much. This doesn't seem to be something that Apple is encouraging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can do to get this information is access their iCloud info via CloudKit.  However, this is still limited to just their first and last name if they choose to allow your app to see it.  You will not be able to obtain their email through this as Apple considers this sensitive information.