# how to get mobile info in codenameone?

Tags: java, android, ios, codenameone

Is there any way that I can get mobile info, such as system information, network, sim card count, and sim card GSM network?

There is native code for Android but for iOS, it would be tricky. Can anyone help?

Comment: Follow this link will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other comments mentioned Apple will scan your binary when you submit to them. If you used an undocumented API to access device information your app will be automatically rejected before it even reaches a human reviewer. This information is explicitly blocked to developers.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this project https://github.com/nisrulz/easydeviceinfo Android library to get device information in a super easy way.