# Is there any way to get own phone number with Contacts Framework?

Tags: swift, swift3, ios9

I use Contacts Framework (introduced in iOS 9) to fetch some phone numbers from the address book.

I need to get my own phone number but I can't find any documentation on this question. Should I use Contacts Framework? Is this even possible? If it is not – how apps like snapchat do this?

Comment: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as it violates user privacy and since 2009 Apple has not allowed for apps to get your phone number straight from your phone without permission.

Comment: But then, the question remains – "how apps like snapchat do this?"

Comment: When you do 2 step verification it gets you phone number