# Getting SIM Card Number using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, submission

I've read a lot of questions about this, and the answer that I saw is that **its' not possible** and there's a possibility that the app will be **rejected**.

One of the requirements that we have is to get the SIM card number of the device to serve as an identifier.

Is there a workaround to get the SIM card number? Also, if there's any, can we have the number encrypted for the app to avoid the rejection?

Thank you!

Comment: Ask yourself first, why do you need the SIM card number? Do you need to uniquely identify the user? If so, why not let the user know and let them decide whether to disclose personal information or not. Prompt for phone number (this is not SIM number though), then send a confirmation SMS to confirm. You still better encrypt the number on your data storage (if you are sending it to your backend)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)