# How to get phone number in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin.forms. I need to get the phone number, if the device is dual sim then I need to get both the numbers. How do I achieve this? There so many questions related to this after referring all I came here.

I created one interface in shard project and implemented the interface in an android project. android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS

created interface in shared project

```
public interface IDeviceInfo
{
 string GetMyPhoneNumber();
}
```

Implemented the interface in android project

```
public string GetMyPhoneNumber()
{
   try
   {
      TelephonyManager mgr =     
  Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService) as TelephonyManager;
    return mgr.Line1Number;
   }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  throw;
  }
}
```

On one of Button click on shared project

```
 private void GetPhone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
    try
    {

        var data = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceInfo>().GetMyPhoneNumber();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          throw;
    }
}
```

When I am using android 5 it is returning the empty string and if I am using android 6+ it is giving permission error like Java.Lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10286 nor current process hasandroid.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.READ_SMS, or android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS

How do resolve this in all android version?

Comment: The error is saying that you can not access the number without user permission in android 6 and above. Please refer to this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: @Jaymin, Ok I understood that it requires run time permission but when I use android 5 why I am not getting phone number? Why it is not giving?

Comment: That might be a different issue.

Comment: Because Telephony Manager is not a reliable way of getting this

Comment: @G.hakim Than what is the reliable way to get?

Comment: There is no reliable way to get it check my answer and all the links in it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

For iOS, this is not possible and even if you somehow get it using `CoreTelephony` or something else your application would get rejected for apple store deployment with the below issue as stated by Dylan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios):

> "For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system. This restriction is part of the security feature known as the application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on."
>
> The device's phone number is not available within your application's container. You will need to revise your application to read only within your directory container and resubmit your binary to iTunes Connect in order for your application to be reconsidered for the App Store.

Now for `Android`, you could use the `TelephonyManager` approach to get the phone number, but in my knowledge, it is not a reliable approach to do so it does not get the phone number from the sim details or something it picks it up from the device information that you enter at the phone's startup an explanation for it is present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25131061/7462031)

Also, there is an important comment here that seems to be [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480307/7462031)

> Actually, not so perfect. Last time I tried this method, it reported the phone number that my phone originally had, before my old mobile number was ported over to it. It probably still does, as the Settings app still shows that defunct number. Also, there are reports that some SIMs cause this method to return null. That being said, I'm not aware of a better answer.

Even if this somehow is fine with you, you can only get one phone number using this and this phone number would be null most of the times if your user is not configured in the mobile's settings.

### Possible solution (only if you ask me)

The way in which both these issues could get solved is, creating a screen something like a pop-up or a page according to your convenience that asks the user himself to enter the phone number if mandatory make a modal page all together

Good luck

Revert in case of queries

Comment: Hi @G.Hakim, How to get subscriber id of both sim in xamarin forms?

Comment: What do you mean when you say subscriber id?

Comment: @SagarPatil Sorry i just remembered this, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I was stuck in another important work but from tomorrow again I will start working on this. I have one doubt once the user registers their number first in pop up or something, register mobile number should be that device. Whenever the customer opens the app that SIM should be inside the device. How to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can do this in Android but not on iOS, your sim is inaccessible in various ways as sandbox would not allow that, could you explain why are you looking for this?